# set variable instead of full url

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I've got the latest (4.14) CKEditor in a custom CMS. I need to use the `config.contentsCss` setting to load some custom .css files.

The syntax from Ckeditor docs is:

```
config.contentsCss = [ '/css/mysitestyles.css', '/css/anotherfile.css' ];
```

I want to parse a variable instead of a hardcoded path; this is an example from a tpl file (Smarty based CMS):

```
{$smarty.const.THEME_ROOT}/mytheme/style1.css
```

Any idea how I can achieve this?

Comment: What variable? Please add that in your question.

Comment: The variable that I want to pass is: {$smarty.const.THEME_ROOT}

Comment: If you're using PHP, did you try to pass it as-is? Like this: `config.contentsCss = [ "{$smarty.const.THEME_ROOT}/mytheme/style1.css" ];`